# How to get client_assertion for my certificate

Tags: c++, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to write an application to fetch data from Office 365 (using EWS and Graph APIs). I need to write this app in C++ (for platform compatibility) and I need to use certificate based method (I don't want to use client secret based authentication). I am using Client credentials grant flow so there is no user interaction involved.

I am not able to figure out how can I get client_assertion for my certificate. Is there any standard method to get this string?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, here the authentication method is OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a JWT Token

```
urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
```

using your certificate https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/howtos/advanced/jwt-assertion/ that becomes your assertion. With certificate Authentication make sure your use the Tenant specific endpoint (rather then common) and that should be the audience of your assertion eg

```
  "aud": "https://login.windows.net/$TenantId/oauth2/token"
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not clear how to obtain the assertion.

Comment: The assertion needs to be generated from the certificate. AFAIK Microsoft doesn't provide anything in C++ to do this (plenty of .net libaries). So you will need to either come up with your own method to create the assertion or look at some of the other c++ libraries eg https://github.com/arun11299/cpp-jwt that may help.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a really hard time identifying C++ library which can help. Let me try out the Github link you provided.